# Work around for adding multiple roles to the same user

Tags: roles

I have the following role hierarchy:

```
A
|_A1
   |_A1.1
        A2.11
|_A2
   |_A2.1
```

A2.11 and A2.1 are the same roles but since salesforce doesn't allow 2 roles with same name I used 2.11 instead of 2.1. The problem is since they are the same roles, I will have the same users. Since salesforce does not allow a user to have multiple roles, how can I work around this restriction?

Comment: Why do you need A2 then? why not place those users in A1?

Comment: Unfortunately, the structure of the organization is like this. I cannot change it.

Comment: The role hierarchy here needs to simply cover your sharing needs since you have a separate way of editing basic permissions. As such the role hierarchy does not need to exactly reflect the business structure but rather the data visibility structure within the business. For people doing the same type of job in different units you will have the same profile (and/or permission sets) but different roles if the data from each unit is to be "isolated" within the unit (and to higher level roles).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove A2.1 from A2 and create a sharing rule, such that every time a user with role A2.11 creates a record for my custom object it is shared with A2. In this way I dont even have to have these 2 roles that are the same and I dont have to have the same user for these 2 roles.